# How to show Kivy accordionitem at the left side of a vertical oriented Accordion?

Tags: kivy, accordion

I want to create an Accordion widget where the options are vertically stacked and where the AccordionItem opens, when touched, at the left side of the Accordion options list instead of under the touched Accordion option. So actually there are two columns where the right column contains the stacked options and the left column contains the Item content. 
Would this be possible and could you give me some hints/tips on how such code would look like?

**EDIT**

So far I have the following in mobile phone app view.
[image]

The reason I want to have the content at the left side is that I want to make the app available for full screen tablet mode.

The code relating to this is like follows:

The .py file:

```
            # build the list with actions
            acc_panel = screen.ids.acc_panel
            acc_panel.clear_widgets()
            tpitem = string.Template('''
AccordionItem:
    id: '$acc_id'
    title: '$acc_title'
    font_name: 'Roboto'
    min_space: 30
    RstDocument:
        id: rstcontent
        background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        text: '$rstcontent'
            ''')

            for idx in range(0, totevents):
                event = str(idx + 1)
                acc_id = 'acc_' + event
                evidx = 'step' + event

                if wftempInstrData[evidx]['source'] != '':
                    rstcontent = str(process_rstcontent(wftempInstrData[evidx]['content']))
                else:
                    rstcontent = ''

                acc_title = str(wftempInstrData[evidx]['title'])
                new_acc = tpitem.substitute(vars())
                acc = Builder.load_string(new_acc)
                acc_panel.add_widget(acc)

            acclabel[0] = 0
            n = len(acc_panel.children)
            for i in range(0, n):
                acc_panel.children[i].collapse = True
                acclabel[i + 1] = n - 1 - i
                acc_panel.children[i].bind(collapse=self.do_print)
            acc_panel.children[n - 1].collapse = False
            accactive = 1
            wfactiveEvent = 1
```

and the .kv file:

```
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        BoxLayout:
            width: 1
            size_hint_x: None
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: 0.5,0.5,0.5    # mid grijs
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

        Accordion:
            id: acc_panel
            orientation: 'vertical'
            min_space: 30
            font_name: 'Roboto'
            background_selected: './images/dgrTab.png'
            background_normal: './images/dgrTab.png'
```

Comment: Please show what you have so far and also a sketch of what you are aiming at

Comment: Are you sure you need the Accordion? It sounds like this is can be accomplished by other means.

Comment: Please see EDIT in the question.